# Java out of box cacerts certificate are SHA1 is there one with SHA2

Tags: security, java, certificate

Java/JDK/JRE they have a keystore cacerts under lib\Security folder as shown below

[image]

**Java comes with around 93 certificates out of box, These are not self-signed these are supplied by java itself**

[image]

These certificates are SHA1 Certificates

### Background

The application that we use depends upon java and our company saying they are moving away from SHA1 and want to change these SHA1 to SHA2.

### Questions

1. Is there a version/type of java that does uses SHA2 for out of box certs?
2. Is it possible to replace out of box certs with SHA2?

Comment: [Java fully supports SHA2 certificates.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127896/suncertpathbuilderexception-with-sha-2-signed-certificate).  It also is important to point out [cacerts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) also supports SHA2 certificates.  Be sure you know how to import certificates by reading [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/java-add-certificate-ca-store/)

Comment: Oracle is the identity, who would need to issue the default root CAs, to be SHA256 certificates.  [Its not clear if you understand the contents of cacerts or not.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935619/what-is-difference-between-cacerts-and-keystore).  *You can can delete the root CAs then add only SHA256 certificates if you want with the understand a Java update might or might effect the store.*

Comment: Do you understand, its simply the certificate store Java will use, so if you don't want to support SHA1 certificates you don't add SHA1 certificates?  How exactly did you verify that every certificate in the java certificate store is only SHA1?

Comment: Question is edited, these are out of box certs not added by us

Comment: I understand they are "out of box" certificates.  Just remove the SHA1 certificates and replace them with the SHA256 certificates you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late reply, but there's an important misconception in the question that should be cleared for future readers. Keytool output can be misleading: it shows a SHA1 *fingerprint* for all certificates, whether they use SHA1 or SHA2 *signing hash function* (which is what you're looking for). SHA1 fingerprint is simply a unique ID of the certificate.

To find SHA2 certificates in a bundle, you can't rely on keytool -list. You need to extract all certificates with keytool -exportcert, and then check the details for each one with keytool -printcert: SHA2 certificates will have this line in the output:

```
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
```

SHA2 CA certificates have been part of the standard Java cacerts bundle since JRE 1.6.14 (see certificate ttelesecglobalrootclass3ca), if not earlier.

Answer (score 0):

As CA providers upgrade their certificates to SHA-2 they submit the new certificates for inclusion in the various products that use SSL such as browsers and Java.

Obviously, older versions of a given product will not have newer certificates (there is no mechanism to automatically upgrade them).

If the provider does not submit a new certificate it will not be included in Java and you will have to manually add newer certificates into the Java trusted certificate repository.

So if you get an error like:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

... then you probably do not have the **correct** CA root certificate and you will need to manually download and install the certificates into the Java trusted certificate keystore. Here is a method of doing this: http://mikepilat.com/2011/05/adding-a-certificate-authority-to-the-java-runtime.html